# Warning: ftp_fget(): TYPE is now ASCII - Descarga FTP - PHP

Tags: php

Tengo un código que descarga archivos de manera continua desde un servidor.

Hace poco de la nada, y con archivos aleatorios, ha comenzado a aparecer esta alerta, generando que la descarga no sea ejecutada, lo cual es un problema.

Lo que quiero saber, es por que ocurre, o por que puede ocurrir, por que como dije, solo ocurre a veces y con archivos aleatorios. Leí además, que hay que usar ftp_pasv, pero yo si lo tengo implementado, por lo que no es eso.

Si hace falta mostrar código extra, lo agregaré luego.

```
//Conexion.php
$ftp_server="server";
$ftp_user_name="name";
$ftp_user_pass="pass";
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("No se pudo conectar a $ftp_server"); 
$login_result =ftp_login($conn_id,$ftp_user_name,$ftp_user_pass);
ftp_pasv($conn_id,true);
```

---

```
//Uso del ftp_get
if (ftp_fget($conn_id, $handle, $remote_file, FTP_ASCII, 0)) {
    echo "Se ha creado el archivo " . $respaldo_file . " </br>";
    fwrite($txtLogRes, $respaldo_file . PHP_EOL);
} else {
    echo "Ha habido un problema durante la descarga de $remote_file en $respaldo_file </br>";
}
```

---

***UPDATE-1*** - He vuelto a descargar los mismos archivos que dieron la alerta, sin haber realizado cambios al codigo. Y el problema no ha ocurrido. Por lo que quiero saber, es como una descarga pasiva logra cometer esa alerta en ese comando y porque. Para asi poder evitarlo.

Comment: ¿Por qué pusiste el código en dos bloques? Es importante tener claro el contexto, porque el modo pasivo (`ftp_pasv`) **antes** de `ftp_get` debería hacer que ese Warning no salga. Dado que tienes nos bloques de código, no se sabe qué va primero. ¿A qué pertenece el 2do bloque de código?

Comment: Ese es el tema, Como dije, descarga varios archivos recorriendo el servidor, por lo que esta dentro de un `for`. El tema es que, por que a veces sucede, y a veces no. Por que volví a correr los mismos archivos nuevamente, sin cambiar el codigo, y las alertas no aparecieron. Lo que quiero saber, es por que aparece la alerta, y por que me cancela la descarga.

Comment: No sabría decirte. Pero [esta nota de contribución del Manual puede dar una pista](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.ftp-pasv.php#111439). Habla de refrescar la conexión cada X archivos o cada X GB según los tamaños de archivo. FTP es un mundo y es difícil poder saber a qué se debe ese comportamiento aleatorio. Yo en tu caso, haría esto a un nivel aún más bajo,  por ejemplo, en consola directamente mediante un script ssh llamando desde Cron. Sería más rápido, y más seguro.

Comment: Probaré esto, cerrar y abrir la conexion cada vez que realiza una vuelta. Gracias Cedaño !